# WAMP + PHP + PowerShell 2.0 + bat + Outlook + HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT)

Tags: php, powershell, batch-file, outlook, wamp

Holo

I have the nex problem trying to make automatic mailer from website for failure system.

I have WAMP and my code is on php that do many thing, the main porpouse is that this php file crete *.ps1 (Powershell mail), the second part create the *.bat (file that execute *.ps1)

*.ps1 ->

```
$o = New-Object -com Outlook.Application
$mail = $o.CreateItem(0)
$mail.importance = 2
$mail.subject = "bla bla bla"
$mail.body = "bla bla bla"
$mail.To = "email"
$mail.Send()
```

*.bat ->

```
@echo off
"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\PowerShell.exe" -File "*.ps1" > "ok.log" 2> "error.log"
```

This two program work perfectly and i cand send automatic mail, but when i try to execute from web i get this error, i enable userdir_module on apache.

ERROR ->

```
Excepci¢n al llamar a "Send" con los argumentos "0": "Operaci¢n anulada (Excepc
i¢n de HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))"
En *.ps1: 9 Car cter: 11
+ $mail.Send <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

I hope any one have and idea, i continue trying and reading more about this.

Thanks (My english is regular), have a nice night.

Comment: If you want to send mails why don't you send them directly with PHP using swiftmailer for example ?

Comment: If you want to send mails from Powershell, why don't you use [Send-MailMessage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx)

Comment: If for some reason you particularly want to use your current approach, you can add the following line after `$mail.Send()`: `$error[0]|select *; $error[0].innerexception|select *` to get more info about the failure.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google Search for `HRESULT 0x80004004` shows that [Outlook won't let you do this.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/84ae387f-5dd8-421d-b25f-206e5da968f3/operation-aborted-exception-from-hresult-0x80004004-eabort).  Instead, try using PowerShell's [Send-MailMessage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx):

```
Send-MailMessage -Priority High `
                 -Subject "bla bla blah" `
                 -Body "bla bla blah" `
                 -To "email"
```